# CSS Background Image wont work?

Tags: css

```
body{

    margin: 0 auto;

    width: 1000px;

    height: 100%;

    padding-top:150px;
    background: url('images/background.jpg');


    background:#5F755D;
}
```

Okay so, that's the css I'm using and I cannot seem to get the background to change from this ugly colour the background image I want. Any ideas?

Comment: You are overwriting your `background` image with a color.

Comment: This is because of the path I guess. Use absolute path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overwriting the background image, with the color. Change the CSS to this:

```
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top:150px;
    background-color:#5F755D;
    background-image: url('images/background.jpg');
}
```

This way, the color will be shown, if the image cant be found.

Answer (score 0):

You set the background image, and then overwrite by using a color in the next line:

```
background:#5F755D;
```

You will see the image (if it exists) if you remove the above line. Note that the image will repeat itself. You can disable it by using

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just merge your background color and background image like so:

```
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top:150px;
    background:#5F755D url('images/background.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```